# Ошибка NullPointerException при попытке установить текст в Label

Tags: java, javafx

Возникает ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException` при попытке установить текст в  label и считать его из label.

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;  
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;  

public class DialogConroller {

    @FXML
    private static Button btn_savefile;

    @FXML
    private static Label label;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane paneAnch;


    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        paneAnch.setMaxSize(100, 300);
        System.out.println(label.getText().toString());
   //   Platform.runLater((() -> label.setText("")));       
    }      
}
```

Так же были попытки засунуть в отдельный поток, но ни к чему не привело.

Comment: Покажите как вы создаете DialogConroller. Это должен делать fxmlLoader и почему переменные статик

Comment: `FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader();  
     
     load.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/dialog.fxml"));
     try {
   load.load();
   
  } catch (IOException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     Stage stage = new Stage();
     
     Parent root = load.getRoot();
     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,100);
     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.setResizable(false);
     
     stage.showAndWait();` Переменная static, т.к. создалась автоматически через SceneBuilder

Comment: уберите статик у переменных и проверьте, что внутри fxml указано fx:id="label". И Platform.Later тут не нужен, вы в FX потоке в этом методе.

Comment: Убрал статик и все получилось. Теперь вопрос такой, а почему так static повлиял? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не знаю, но IDEA удаляет иконку, отображающую связанность с .fxml файлом, если стоит static.

Answer (score 1):

`FXMLLoader` не внедряет данные в переменные, объявленные как `static`. 
Нужно убрать `static` с переменных.

`ResourceBundle` и `Location`, если не используются, можно убрать. 
Так же вызов `initialize()` производит fxmlolder внутри FX потока, поэтому `Platform.runLater()` здесь лишний.